# How to find longest match in a query sentence using SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, string-matching

Let say I have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------
|id |phrase
----------------------------------
|1  |real
|2  |testing
|3  |real message
|4  |testing message
|5  |special testing message
```

The target is to find id of the longest match in a query sentence. For example, a query sentense `This is a testing message` should return `4`.

I am using PHP with MySQL, so if it is too complicated to do in SQL alone, part of the operation can be switched to PHP. Currently I am getting the whole table out and do regex one by one on PHP, but it is inefficient if the table get large. Is there a way to switch some workload to SQL so that I don't need to store the whole table into memory?

Comment: Try the LEN() function. [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_func_len.asp)

Comment: @JoãoPaulodeLima How do LEN() help with this problem?

Comment: Sorry cytsunny. Actually I thoughr you wanted to get the longest phrase. But now I see that it need to match your sentense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CONCAT`, `LENGTH` with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE ('.$search_term.' LIKE CONCAT("%",phrase,"%"))
ORDER BY LENGTH(phrase) DESC LIMIT 1
```